# using vsftpd with inotify IN_CLOSE_WRITE event

Tags: inotify, vsftpd

I'm trying to write event based ftp server that notifies me when some user uploads any file(users will never do any delete or other stuff, they just upload). Apache ftpServer with ftplets is what I need but it is java based and does not satisfy my environment. So what I'm planning to do is to run `vsftpd` and  another process besides it which listens to `IN_CLOSE_WRITE` event. When `vsftpd` close the file descriptor after finishing file upload, my process will be notified and I will do some appropriate action. My questions are:

1. Is it possible that I miss any file upload?
2. Is it possible that `IN_CLOSE_WRITE` fired in other situations that I get inconsistent files instead of ready to use files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. if the incrond service crashes or is stopped you will loose notification during that time
2. `IN_CLOSE_WRITE` should work.